# How to import data from a csv into Excel using EPPlus?

Tags: c#, csv, epplus

Does epplus provide a method to import data from a csv file into an Excel document?

Answer (score 10):

EPPlus is a library for working with .XLSX files, which it does incredibly well, but it does not support .CSV files.

Take a look at CsvHelper on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) - it's a lightweight and high-performance library for reading and writing CSV files. You'll find the documentation and plenty of samples [here](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). The project is regularly updated and well maintained - I've found it to be a good choice.

Comment: Not true, see: https://riptutorial.com/epplus/example/26605/import-data-from-csv-file

Comment: An interesting example, but this does not demonstrate EPPlus reading CSV files directly. It does. however, demonstrate creating a spreadsheet from data read from a text file. The example works fine for basic CSVs, but once you start encountering line breaks, escaped characters, etc. in your source data you may well run into problems. Better to use something like CSVHelper to read the CSV, and then use the output to create a spreadsheet with EPPlus if that is your end goal.

Comment: `ExcelRangeBase.LoadFromText()` is one of a number of data load methods:  https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Reading-and-Writing-Data. It supports a `ExcelTextFormat` that allows you to specify information on the culture, line endings, skip headers, and column types.